# How to count the number of elements Stream has processed?

Tags: java, json, java-8, java-stream

Here is my example

I have a `Person` class that looks like

```
class Person {
    List<String> keys;
    Map<String, String> attributes;

    public Person(List<String> keys, Map<String, String> attributes) {
      this.keys = keys;
      this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public List<String> getKeys() {
      return keys;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
      return attributes;
    }
  }
```

I process some `persons` as stream and convert them to `JSON` as

```
  @Test
  public void testPersonStreamToFile() throws Exception {
    Person person1 = new Person(Collections.singletonList("key1"), Collections.singletonMap("person1", "key1"));
    Person person2 = new Person(Collections.singletonList("key2"), Collections.singletonMap("person2", "key2"));

    File file = temporaryFolder.newFile("personStream.txt");
    System.out.println(file.toString());

    List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(person1, person2);

    Stream<String> personStream = persons
      .stream()
      .map(WorkflowTest::mapToJsonString);


    Files.write(Paths.get(file.toURI()), (Iterable<String>) personStream::iterator);
    System.out.println("Done");
  }
```

**Required**
As I process the stream, I want to keep an `Counter` that tells me by the end of program how many `persons` were converted to `JSON`.

How can I achieve this with `Streams`?

Comment: There's a `peek` method you can use to keep a counter.

Comment: If this is going to happen to every single element (as in, there isn't a conditional that factors out some elements), the `stream` has a `count()` function that will return the elements within it.

Comment: Or you could increment some counter inside the JSON conversion method.

Comment: @shmosel: that would be a terrible thing from separation of concerns point

Comment: Why not use `persons.size()` ?

Comment: You really shouldn't be converting a `Stream` to an `Iterable` like that...

Comment: @mszymborski I would need to see more of the context to come to such a strong conclusion, but I see your point.

Comment: Please guide me as to what to do, `Persons` Ideally would be an `Iterable` that would fill up based on an API call

Comment: @SusannahPotts `count()` is a *terminal operation*, which means the stream would be unusable after calling it.

Comment: @shmosel really?  I didn't know, thank you.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Would you recommend instead `() -> persons.stream().map(WorkflowTest::mapToJsonString).iterator()`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Nah, you'd probably recommend `Iterables.transform(persons, WorkflowTest::mapToJsonString)` ;)

Comment: No.  I'd recommend not using `Files.write`, but instead opening a `BufferedWriter` and doing `.forEachOrdered(stream::println)`.

Comment: Well, I have another requirement where I encrypt `person` using a `map` function. Would `Iterables.transform` still work?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, any specific reason for it?

Comment: (no seriously I would _not_ recommend `Iterables.transform` when streams are available)

Comment: You should never create an `Iterable` that only can be iterated over once, and streams are single-use only.  If you need to convert a `Stream` to an `Iterable` then use `.collect(toList())`.  (But you _don't_ need to convert the `Stream` to an `Iterable`; there are better ways of dealing with your problem.)

Comment: I guess I forgot my original question ;-)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I often find Guava's helpers to be cleaner and more concise than their stream counterparts. Are they officially discouraged?

Comment: Not to mention the ability to create views rather than having to copy collections.

Comment: No, they're not discouraged, but we don't find them cleaner or more concise, and while intermediate view collections are useful we find you usually want to end up with a concrete collection.

Comment: @shmosel: using `() -> persons.stream().map‌​(WorkflowTest::mapToJ‌​sonString).iterator()‌` would be a working solution creating a conforming iterable.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: unfortunately, `.forEachOrdered(writer::println)` doesn’t work. `BufferedWriter` has no `println` method and all of its methods throw checked exceptions. A `PrintWriter` has a `println` method that could work, but swallowing exceptions is even worse than all other approaches…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `peek` operation like this:

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

Stream<String> personStream = persons
  .stream()
  .map(WorkflowTest::mapToJsonString)
  .peek(str -> counter.incrementAndGet());
```

After your operation `counter.get()` will show you how many times `mapToJsonString` was invoked here.

Comment: When running SONAR, peek is said to be for debugging. Is there a better solution for using peek?

Answer (score 0):

Try `forEach`.

In the given example, since you are just mapping elements of given stream, the size would the same as the `count` (a terminal operation, after you are done with the stream). But if you are filtering elements based on certain criterion, you could use `forEach` later to do the bookkeeping. How about the following?

```
public class StreamFilter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
        IntStream.of(1, 2, 3)
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .forEach(
                i -> {
                    // do something with the i, e.g. write to file
                    count.incrementAndGet(); // use return value
                });
        System.out.println(count.intValue());
    } }
```